# How can I obtain a regularized value of this integral using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I want to know the regularized value of this integral. Wolfram Mathematica fails.
$$\int_0^\infty \psi'(x+1)dx$$

I have two conjectures, it is either $\gamma$ or $0$.

I attempted

```
Sum[f[s x],{x,1,Infinity},Regularization->"Borel"]//FullSimplify

Limit[s %,s→0]
```

with all available regularization methods instead of "Borel" but Mathematica produced no result.

Comment: What is psi, what is gamma, what is prime. When you ask a question you really should define your terms.

Comment: ... also, which regularization in particular? the result is non-unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HoldForm[PolyGamma[1, 1 + x] == Sum[1/(1 + k + x)^2, {k, 0, Infinity}]] // TeXForm
```

$$\psi ^{(1)}(1+x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(1+k+x)^2}$$
Then:

```
INT = Integrate[1/(1 + k + x)^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/(1 + k), Im[k] != 0 || Re[k] >= -1] *)

INT[[1]] 
(* 1/(1 + k) *)

Sum[INT[[1]], {k, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
(* EulerGamma *)
```

Another way:

$\int_0^{\infty } \psi ^{(1)}(1+x) \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t
   (1+x)} t}{1-e^{-t}} \, dt\right) \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\int_0^{\infty }
   \frac{e^{-t (1+x)} t}{1-e^{-t}} \, dx\right) \, dt=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{-1+e^t} \,
   dt=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \exp (-j t)\right) \, dt=\sum
   _{j=1}^{\infty } \int_0^{\infty } \exp (-j t) \, dt=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty }
   \frac{1}{j}=\gamma$

Last sum with `Borel` regularization.

Comment: I wonder what does [[1]] mean and what elements are necessary (I think texform is not?)

Comment: @Anixx It means `[[1]]` extract form `ConditionalExpression` a  `1/(1 + k)`.

Comment: So, the answer is $\gamma$ to my disappointment

Comment: @Anixx It seems so.

Comment: I suspected this because $$\int_0^\infty \psi'(x+1)dx-\gamma=\psi(\infty)=\ln(\infty)=\int_1^\infty \frac1xdx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k-\gamma=0$$ (the concept of divergent limits at infinity would be infinitely useful)